# How to vectorize a for loop

Tags: r

i am beginner with R and i am trying to avoid for loops. This is my code:

```
NII <-280
NJJ<-237
#CUTK  is a nonegative matrix 282x239
ADVDOM <- array(0, dim=c(282,239))
for(i in seq(1,NII + 2){
  for(j in seq(1,NJJ + 2)){
    if(CUTK[i,j] > 0){
      iplus <- trunc(15* CUTK[i,j] / 4)
      jplus <- trunc(15* CUTK[i,j] / 4)

      for(i1 in seq(i - iplus, i + iplus + 1)){
        for(j1 in seq(j - jplus, j+ jplus)){
          if(i1 <= NII + 1 && i1 > 1 && j1 <= NJJ + 1 && j1 > 1){
            ADVDOM[i1,j1] <- 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

These are my attemps, but they don't work. I can't spot the mistakes.

```
#1
i <- 1 : (NII + 2)
j <- 1 : (NJJ + 2)
outer(i,j, Vectorize(function(i,j){
  if(CUTK[i,j] > 0){
    iplus <- trunc(15* CUTK[i,j] / 4)
    jplus <- trunc(15* CUTK[i,j] / 4)

    i1 <- (i - iplus) : (i + iplus + 1)
    j1 <- (j - jplus) : (j + jplus)

    outer(i1,j1,Vectorize(function(i1,j1){
      if(i1 <= NII + 1 && i1 > 1 && j1 <= NJJ + 1 && j1 > 1){
        ADVDOM[i1,j1] <- 1
      }
    }))
  }
}))
#2
sapply(1: NII + 2 , function(i){
  sapply(1: NJJ + 2, function(j){
    if(CUTK[i,j] > 0){
      iplus <- trunc(15* CUTK[i,j] / 4)
      jplus <- trunc(15* CUTK[i,j] / 4)

      sapply(i - iplus: i + iplus + 1 , function(i1){
        sapply(j - jplus : j + jplus, function(j1){
          if(i1 <= NII + 1 && i1 > 1 && j1 <= NJJ + 1 && j1 > 1){
            ADVDOM[i1,j1] <- 1
          }
        })
      })
    }
  })
})

#3
ij <- expand.grid(i=1:(NII + 2), j=1:(NJJ + 2))
invisible(apply(ij,1, function(ij){
  if(CUTK[ij[1],ij[2]] > 0){
    iplus <- trunc(PrognosticSubDomainFactor * CUTK[i,j] / DXK)
    jplus <- trunc(PrognosticSubDomainFactor * CUTK[i,j] / DYK)

    ijplus <- expand.grid(ip = (ij[1] - iplus):(ij[1] + iplus + 1), jp = (ij[2] - jplus):(ij[2] + jplus) )
    apply(ijplus, 1 , function(ijplus){
      if(ijplus[1] <= NII + 1 && ijplus[1] > 1 && ijplus[2] <= NJJ + 1 && ijplus[2] > 1){
        ADVDOM[ijplus[1],ijplus[2]] <- 1
      }
    })
  }
}))
```

I would like to undestand this technique of vectorization in R. 
I have some secondary questions:

1. how can avoid the printing after solutions #1 and #2? I tried
   `invisible()`in #3, but i don't know if there is a easier solution.
2. should i have used `mapply`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is much simpler, only has one `for` loop and produces the same result. It starts by creating an index matrix telling where `CUTK` is positive and then uses that matrix throughout the rest of the code.

```
ADVDOM2 <- array(0, dim = c(282, 239))

non.zeros <- which(CUTK > 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
iplus <- trunc(15*CUTK[non.zeros]/4)
jplus <- trunc(15*CUTK[non.zeros]/4)
ip1 <- pmax(2, non.zeros[, 'row'] - iplus)
ip2 <- pmin(NII + 1, non.zeros[, 'row'] + iplus + 1)
jp1 <- pmax(2, non.zeros[, 'col'] - jplus)
jp2 <- pmin(NJJ + 1, non.zeros[, 'col'] + jplus)
for(k in seq_along(iplus)){
  i <- ip1[k]:ip2[k]
  j <- jp1[k]:jp2[k]
  ADVDOM2[i, j] <- 1
}

identical(ADVDOM, ADVDOM2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of CUTK and in the interests of pointing you in the right direction only, I'm just going to quickly say: You don't NEED loops to access each element of a matrix. For example, see how R works to access each item automagically:

```
a <- matrix(c(1:9),nrow=3, ncol=3) 
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    4    7
#[2,]    2    5    8
#[3,]    3    6    9

ifelse(a<5,0,1)      # assign to a named var if no output wanted
#    [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    0    1
#[2,]    0    1    1
#[3,]    0    1    1
```

Since you access a second matrix and might think this is a problem, it isn't. R takes care of the indexing (make sure ranks are same or multiples):

```
b <- t(a)           # t() is the transpose function
ifelse(a>b,1,0)     # assign to a named var if no output wanted
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    1    1
#[2,]    0    0    1
#[3,]    0    0    0
```